# Why is swap memory faster than auxiliary memory though swap is taken from auxiliary memory

Tags: linux

I was asked in the interview regarding O.S

```
we make virtual memory out of hard disk than why is accesing swap faster than accessing hard disk.
```

Please help me understanding the concept.Or else redirect me to the proper forum.

Comment: I think the question should be "What's the point in using swap space anyway? How is it supposed to make the system faster?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, as @Celada said, there's chances your data will in memory (has not been swaped out) when you map your file to memory or put your data in memory. This may be faster than you directly access your file or your data.
- Second, OSes have very efficient swap algorithm that probably better than yours. So for example, if you need to read a very large file(maybe 2GB large or more), you need to do kind of swapping yourself and probably much slower than using OS swap.
- Third, in practice, system administrators usually put `/swap` in a separate partitions or even separate disk or even faster device, so you can take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis is nonsense. Accessing swap is not faster than accessing the hard disk if the swap **is on** the hard disk.

Comment: does your answer mean that both swap and hard disk have same speed for accessing? If so then question itself is wrong??am i right

Comment: If swap is **on** the hard disk, pure logic dictates that accessing swap is at least as slow as accessing the hard disk. Now if your swap is on something else than a hard disk that's a different story!